# MVC: Binding Dropdownlist To Controller and getting Selected index in the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, model, controller

I have an MVC# drop down list with the values defined in a model.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.myModel, new SelectList(Model.List, "Value", "Text"))
```

I want it to act like a button, ie, upon selection, an action is performed in the controller and returned to the same view. I have created a controller method for it like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? selectedIndex)
{

}
```

I am wondering how i could get the selected index from the view. ie, how do i bind a particular dropdownlist to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

`@Html.DropDownListFor` renders an html `input` tag which won't post to the server when the selection changed.

You have to use some javascript / jQuery to capture the change event of the dropdown and post the value to the server like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myModel").on('change', function(e) {
        $.post('@Url.Action("Index")', {id: $(this).val()}, 
               function(data) {
                  // here data contains the response from your action index
               });
    });
});
```